# Can boolean logic be applied to Java @Annotations?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am looking to find out if it is possible to apply boolean logic on annotations in Java. The explanation below should make things clear.

I have a field 'number' that must either be a 10 digit number or a Phone Number that I've put clear-cut constraints on. I want the field to be validated in a POST request to accept either only this unique pattern OR the phone number and nothing else. Is there a way around this using annotations? I'd love if the following were doable

```
@Pattern(regexp=[0-9]{10})
@Or
@PhoneNumberConstraint
private String number;
```

Comment: Just use a regex for both: `@Pattern(regexp="\\d{10}|phonenumberegex")`

Comment: Code that will use those annotations would have to expect logical operators - you can write your own to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As far i know about annotations , they are pré processed by some other program with reflection operation.
Making the assumption that the sequence of the annotations cant be guessed, i should put a property like id or something, for example "@PhoneNumberConstraint(id=1) @Pattern(id=2, regexp=[0-9]{10})" and into the @Or another propertie to identify them both so you know what of the annotations are to be put into the logic chain for ex "@Or(check=[1,2]).

Answer (score -1):

You can use implement combined logic in a single custom annotation.